# Symfony2 create web service

Tags: web-services, symfony, bundle, webservice-client

I am trying to create a web service in Symfony. I have looked at these webs, and tried them all, but they do not work for me.

> http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapserver/configuration.html
>
> http://barandigoyen.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/como-implementar-un-web-service-wsdl-en-symfony-2/

Could anyone explain the process better, step by step, please?

Thanks a lot!!!

EDITED: The steps I have followed are:

1) Added the following to composer.json

```
"require":{
...
        "besimple/soap-bundle": "dev-master",
        "besimple/soap-common": "dev-master",
        "ass/xmlsecurity":      "dev-master",
        "besimple/soap-server": "dev-master",
        "besimple/soap-client": "dev-master"
...
}
```

2) Run the following:

```
$ php composer.phar self-update
$ php composer.phar update
```

3) Added the following to app/AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        new BeSimple\SoapBundle\BeSimpleSoapBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```

4) Added the followin to app/config/config.yml

```
be_simple_soap:
cache:
    type:     disk
    lifetime: 86400
    limit:    5
services:
    AplicationService:
        namespace:      http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/ws/AplicationService
        binding:        rpc-literal
        resource:       “@StaticBundle/Controller/WebServiceController.php“
        resource_type:  annotation
```

5) Added the following to app/config/routing.yml

```
_besimple_soap:
    resource: "@BeSimpleSoapBundle/Resources/config/routing/webservicecontroller.xml"
    prefix:   /ws
```

6) Create the following Controller in StaticBundle

```
namespace myproject\StaticBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class WebServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Soap\Method("hello")
     * @Soap\Param("name", phpType = "string")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return sprintf('Hello %s!', $name);
    }

    /**
     * @Soap\Method("goodbye")
     * @Soap\Param("name", phpType = "string")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
     */
    public function goodbyeAction($name)
    {
        return $this->container->get('besimple.soap.response')->setReturnValue(sprintf('Goodbye %s!', $name));
    }
}
```

7) Access to `localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/ws/AplicationService?wsdl` and get a xml with error code 500.

Comment: can you provide your code ?? Else we cannot help you !

Comment: I have edited it. Is it ok now to answer? Thanks.

Comment: have you added something in the security.yml ?

Comment: nothing for this purpose. Do I have to add anything?

Answer (score 1):

Well, checking the logs I found the cause of this issue:
correct the double quotes of the config.yml:

```
resource:       "@StaticBundle/Controller/WebServiceController.php"
```

[their example](http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapserver/configuration.html) has weird double quotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

In step 6 it appears you are missing the `use` statement for Soap in your annotation.
http://besim.pl/SoapBundle/soapserver/configuration.html#annotations-for-controllers

try:

```
namespace myproject\StaticBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

class WebServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Soap\Method("hello")
     * @Soap\Param("name", phpType = "string")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
     */
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return sprintf('Hello %s!', $name);
    }

    /**
     * @Soap\Method("goodbye")
     * @Soap\Param("name", phpType = "string")
     * @Soap\Result(phpType = "string")
     */
    public function goodbyeAction($name)
    {
        return $this->container->get('besimple.soap.response')->setReturnValue(sprintf('Goodbye %s!', $name));
    }
}
```